# Sieving integers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

Let $2=p_1,p_2,\cdots ,p_n$ be the first $n$ prime numbers.
Suppose  $N$ is a natural number and that $A=\{a+1,\cdots, a+N\}$ be a set of $N$ consecutive integers.
 Let $P_n=p_1\cdot p_2\cdot \cdots p_n$  and  $G_A=\{x:x\in A : \gcd(x,P_n)=1\}$
What is the maximum value of $|G_A|$?
In other words:At least how many integers from the set $A$ will be sieved by the first $n$ primes?

I would like to see (if it is possible) an elementary method-result .
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't understand this situation as well as we would like to, particularly when $A$ is between say $n$ and $n^2$. It's related to the [Jacobsthal function](http://oeis.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_function) on primorials, if you want to do some digging around.

Comment: So we don't know anything about $|G_A|$?I know that is related to $j(n)$ but how exactly?

Comment: One talks about how few integers could be sieved out, the other about how many integers could be sieved out. I thought pointing out the mysterious nature of the latter might give you insight as to the difficulties of the former. In general, the smaller $N$ is relative to $n$, the harder the problem is - that's what sieve theory tries to address as best it can.